# Posting FormData object with input types and file NullPointerException

Tags: java, html, jquery, servlets

I am trying to do a `jquery ajax` post with an input type file and a normal input type with text and retrieving them from my servlet with `request.getParameter("element_name")` however although when using Chrome inspector I am seeing that the object of FormData I am sending contains my file and my text value, the `servlet` is reading the parameter as `null` for some reason.

This is the **form** I have: (ticket_id is returning successfully from another jsp)

```
<form id="upload-form" action="upload" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post">
    <input id="attach-btn" type="file" name="uploadedFile" style="display:none"/>
    <input id="tick-id-upload" type="hidden" name="ID" value="<%=ticket_id%>" />            
    <input id="submit-form" type="button" style="display:none"/>
</form>
```

This is the **jquery ajax post call**:

```
// use to refresh section on submit of a form
$(document).on('click', '#submit-form', function()
{
    var form_data = null;

    if (drop === false)
    {
        // form data object with ticket id and file
        form_data = new FormData($('#upload-form')[0]);
    }
    else
    {
        // append dropped file and value of id seperately
        form_data = new FormData();
            form_data.append('ID', $('#tick-id-upload').val());
        form_data.append('uploadedFile', dropped_files);
    }

    $.ajax(
    {
       url: $('#upload-form').attr('action'),
       type: 'POST',
       async: true, 
       xhr: function() // custom XMLHttpRequest
       {
            myXhr = $.ajaxSettings.xhr();

            if (myXhr.upload)
            { // check if upload property exists
                myXhr.upload.addEventListener('progress', show_progress, false); // for handling the progress of the upload
            }
            return myXhr;
       },
       dataType: 'html', // the data type to be returned
       success: function(response, status, xhr)
       { 
            $('#progressbar').hide();

            if (xhr.getResponseHeader('duplicate') === 'true')
            {
                // file is duplicate.. display dialog box
            setTimeout(function()
            {
                   $('#trigger-dialog').trigger('click');
            }, 10);     
            }
            else
            {
                // replace attachments section by section in response
                    $('#attachments').html($(response).find('#attachments').html());  
                    execute_attach_datatable();
                    switch_to_view();

                    init_progress_bar();
                    override_section_height();
                }
            },   
            error: function(xhr, status, error) 
            {
                alert(xhr.responseText);
            },
            data: form_data , // what data to pass
            cache: false,
            contentType: false,  // type of data to be sent
            processData: false
        }); 
    });
```

And this is what I do in my **doPost** method in my servlet:

```
int ticket_id = Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("ID"));
```

This line is returning a `NullPointerException` although the data is being sent as seen from the Network section in Chrome.

Please note that I have no problem uploading the file without sending the input type text. i.e. when I have the same form without the `tick-id-upload` element, and use the same `jquery ajax` call, the file is uploaded successfully.

Any ideas of what is happening? Many thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot read the `multipart/form` request params directly by using `request.getParameter()`. Instead you need to read different parts of the mulitpart request using [getPart](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpServletRequest.html#getParts%28%29) method. Here is how you can iterate over your multipart request parts:

```
for (Part part : request.getParts()) {
}
```

Follow this blog for a detailed example: http://balusc.blogspot.in/2009/12/uploading-files-in-servlet-30.html

Comment: oh didn't know that thanks for your answer! The blog is really detailed I can follow it easily. Thanks again :)

Comment: @Bernice No probs :-) If you find my answer useful then please accept it. Accepting the answer helps others facing the same problem.

Comment: Please note that apart from this solution, one can use FileItem class in Java, parse the request and get both the file or items :) I don't know if I should put this as another answer for other users